# Inner join on multiple properties

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two databases `test1`, `test2` and they both have a table `company` with columns `company_name` and `people`. Now I want to select the names of the companies that are in both tables and I achieve it with this query:

```
SELECT t1.company_name
FROM dblink('dbname=test1',
            'select company_name from company where companyid IS NOT NULL'
           ) AS t1(company_name name)
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT company_name
      FROM dblink('dbname=test2',
                  'select company_name from company where companyid IS NOT NULL'
                 ) AS t2(company_name name)
     ) AS t3(company_name)
ON t1.company_name=t3.company_name;
```

But now I want to get the companies in both tables if they have the same `company_name` and `people`. I tried to add equality at the end of the query above but it didn't work.

Comment: it would be much easier if you `create foreign table` instead?..

Comment: You can't this is how they are given

Answer (score 1):

You' have to add `people` to

- the dblink `SELECT`s
- the table aliases `t1` and `t2`
- the `JOIN` condition

Comment: here is what I did : SELECT t1.company_name,t1.people
FROM dblink('dbname=test1',
            'select company_name,people from company where companyid IS NOT NULL'
           ) AS t1(company_name name ,people name)
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT company_name
      FROM dblink('dbname=test2',
                  'select company_name,people from company where companyid IS NOT NULL'
                 ) AS t2(company_name name ,people name)
     ) AS t3(company_name,people)
ON t1.company_name=t3.company_name AND t1.people = t3.people;

Comment: But I get the following error : ERROR:  table "t3" has 1 columns available but 2 columns specified